# Create custom LeaveOneGroupOut cross-validator that allows for subsets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a dataset with two groups. For my cross-validation strategy it is important, that a (training or test) fold always only contains samples from one of these groups. Using `sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut` already goes in the right direction, but it doesn't allow to draw subsets, which means that `n_splits` can never be higher than the number of groups in your sample. What I am looking for is to extend `sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut` by also drawing subsets from the groups thus leading to more folds with fewer samples in each fold.

Example data:

```py
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(16).reshape(8,2)
y = np.arange(8)
groups = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
```

In this example, the minimum `n_splits` would be 2 (which is the same as using `LeaveOneGroupOut`) but the maximum `n_splits` could be 8 meaning that each sample forms a single training or test fold at one point. Have I overseen a cross-validation algorithm from `sklearn` that can achieve this splitting-strategy? If not, I would be happy to receive some code that can do this.

P.S.: A nice cherry on top would be, if this algorithm would allow for both non-random folds (train and test folds are drawn by slicing the dataset into chunks) and random folds (train and test folds are formed by randomly drawing *n* samples from either of the two groups).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for now:

```py
# create data
import numpy as np

# user settings
sample_size = 100
group_probablities = [0.6,0.4]

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
X = np.arange(sample_size*2).reshape(sample_size,2)
y = np.arange(sample_size)
groups = rng.choice(a=[1,2],size=sample_size,p=group_probablities)
groups = np.sort(groups)

# user settings
n_splits = 4

def grouped_kfold_subsetted(groups,n_splits):

    # get unique group labels (because they don't always have to be 0 and 1) and
    # count how often a certain group is present
    unique_groups,group_counts = np.unique(groups, return_counts=True)
    
    # get the size of the smallest group. This will determine how big/small 
    # a fold can maximally get
    smallest_group_size = np.min(group_counts)
    fold_size = smallest_group_size // n_splits
    
    if n_splits > smallest_group_size:
        raise ValueError('Number of folds must not be greater than the number of samples in the smallest group')
    if fold_size == 1:
        raise ValueError('Training folds must contain at least two samples. Choose a smaller n_splits to increase fold size')
    
    train_and_test_idxs = []
    group_switch = 0
    fold_start = 0
    
    for split in range(n_splits):
        
        # decide which of the two groups will form the train and the test fold
        train_group = unique_groups[group_switch]
        test_group = unique_groups[~group_switch]
    
        # get all training and testing indices (we will subset afterwards)
        train_idxs = np.where(groups == train_group)[0] 
        test_idxs = np.where(groups == test_group)[0]
    
        # subset training idxs chosen fold size
        fold_end = fold_start + fold_size
        train_idxs = train_idxs[fold_start:fold_end]
        
        # Optional: Make test set equally large as training set
        # test_idxs = test_idxs[fold_start:fold_end]
        train_and_test_idxs.append((train_idxs,test_idxs))
        
        # in the next cycle the other group will from the train fold
        group_switch = 1 - group_switch
        
        # this has to happen every 2nd cycle because each of the groups 
        # wil a train fold (so we start )
        if split % 2 != 0 and split != 0:
            fold_start = fold_end
        
    return train_and_test_idxs

train_and_test_idxs = grouped_kfold_subsetted(groups, n_splits)
```